# i want to compare my sum of Q2 with the sum of all individual account

Tags: python, pandas

I want my option 3 work out. I want to compare the sum of Apr, May, Jun with the sum of every individual accounts. (sum of column compare to sum of axis) I keep getting the series lengths must match to compare

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    file_name = "sales_rossetti.xlsx"    

# Formatting numbers (e.g. $1,000,000)
pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.0f}'.format

# Reading Excel file
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, index_col = 0, convert_float = False)
print ("Welcome to Rossetti's Sales program\n")  
print ("1) Search by State")
print ("2) Search by Jan Sales")
print ("3) Search by Q2 sales")
print ("4) Exit")

my_option = input ("Please select a menu option:")


if (my_option=="3"):
    my_columns = ["Apr","May","Jun"] 
    all_columns = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
    your_sales = input ("Please enter your minimum sale: ")
    print (df[my_columns].sum()<df[all_columns].sum(axis=1, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=True))'
```

Error message is:"
  File "C:\Users\jay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 735, in wrapper
    raise ValueError('Series lengths must match to compare')

ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare"

Comment: We can't guess how your `df` looks like if you don't give a sample...

Comment: It would also help if you included the entire error message.

Comment: File "C:\Users\jay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 735, in wrapper
    raise ValueError('Series lengths must match to compare')

ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare

Answer (score 0):

If you print out the result of `df[my_columns].sum()` and `df[all_columns].sum(axis=1, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=True)` you would probably be able to debug it for yourself.

My guess is that because you have different values for skipna the first series has dropped some rows so you cannot compare them directly.

Comment: i think what happen is that the lists are compare in string instead of integer but i don't how to fix it.                                                   

Please select a menu option:3

Please enter your minimum sale: 65000000
Apr    True
May    True
Jun    True
dtype: bool'

Comment: The error says "Series lengths must match to compare". Do your series lengths match? len(series) or series.shape will tell you this. If you can't figure out how to get them the same length, then create a simple example with actual data, and ask for help on that (in a different question). But like I said in my answer, I expect it is because you have skipna=None for one of the series which is why the series are no longer matching.